# Delete absence data if there is a presence?

Tags: r, sorting, if-statement, delete-row

I have a dataset like this in R:

```
ROW_NAMES   PRES_AB  LON       LAT    

56129606       1     -109.8236 44.11312
56129606       0     -109.8236 44.11312
56129607       1     -109.7474 44.10961
56129607       0     -109.7474 44.10961
56129608       0     -109.6709 44.12495
56129609       0     -109.6285 44.11815
56129610       0     -109.5649 44.11377
56129611       0     -109.4849 44.11273
56129611       1     -109.4849 44.11273
```

Column 1 is my assigned names to rows which are the names of USDA plots in Wyoming, column 2 is presence / absence data of a species in a plot, column 3 is the longitude coordinate of a plot, and column 4 is the latitude coordinate of the plot.

You can see that the first two rows have presence (`PRES_AB=1`) and absence (`PRES_AB=0`) assigned to the same plot (`56129606`).  The same goes for the third and fourth rows as well as the last two rows.  I want to delete rows where `PRES_AB=0` **if** there is a presence for the plot (if there is already a `PRES_AB=1`).  My data should then look like this:

```
ROW_NAMES   PRES_AB  LON       LAT    

56129606       1     -109.8236 44.11312
56129607       1     -109.7474 44.10961
56129608       0     -109.6709 44.12495
56129609       0     -109.6285 44.11815
56129610       0     -109.5649 44.11377
56129611       1     -109.4849 44.11273
```

By the way, this is a dataset of 81,000 rows and I am just showing a portion of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say your data is in data frame `a`, then this should do the trick:

```
a[!(a$ROW_NAMES %in% a[a$PRES_AB==1,'ROW_NAMES'] & a$PRES_AB==0),]
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using subsetting and the `%in%` function:

```
> test.data <- data.frame(cbind(ROW_NAMES=c("A", "A", "B", "C", "D", "D"), PRES_AB=c(1,0,1,0,1,0), OTHER_DATA=c("bla", "bla", "bla", "etc", "etc", "etc")))
> test.data
  ROW_NAMES PRES_AB OTHER_DATA
1         A       1        bla
2         A       0        bla
3         B       1        bla
4         C       0        etc
5         D       1        etc
6         D       0        etc


> test.data[!(test.data[,"ROW_NAMES"] %in% (test.data[test.data[,"PRES_AB"]==1, "ROW_NAMES"]) & (test.data[,"PRES_AB"]==0)),]

  ROW_NAMES PRES_AB OTHER_DATA
1         A       1        bla
3         B       1        bla
4         C       0        etc
5         D       1        etc
```

Answer (score 0):

My answer is in two steps, because that's usually how I think through the logic of which rows to choose.

First I make a column with information on how many observations there are for each `ROW_NAME`.

```
require(plyr)
# Add column with information on how many observations for each ROW_NAME
dat1 = ddply(dat1, .(ROW_NAMES), transform, numid = length(PRES_AB) )
```

Once I have that information, I can use logical operators to extract only the ROW_NAMES with less than 2 observations OR (if more than 1 observation) when PRES_AB is 1.

```
# subset dataset with subset() (or use extract, "[")
   # remove extra column "numid" for neatness
subset(dat1, numid < 2 | PRES_AB == 1, -numid)
```